# Blender 2.79: Model Looks Disfigured When Using Viewport Render

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

[image: The dog on the left is the viewport render one and the dog on the right is what I see when working on it]

I'm trying to render this animation using the viewport render button, but the model comes out disfigured and I'm not sure why. This is in cycles with only textures. I don't know if this is an issue with some settings or the rigging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clipping start was set to 0.1, causing some parts to be clipped. All I had to do was set it to a larger value